# Alternate for deprecated methods in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

To get User Name or User Email,

```
com.day.cq.security.profile.Profile
```

can be used. But it is depricated from CQ5.5.
What should be the work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the classes from `org.apache.jackrabbit.api.security.user` package. You can access `User` via the `UserManager` (which you can get by calling `adaptTo(UserManager.class)` on a `ResourceResolver`). `User` supports the `getProperty` method, which can be used to get `"profile/email"`, `"profile/familyName"`, etc.

**EDIT**

The `WorkflowProcess.execute` method has WorkflowSession parameter. To access the `UserManager` from a `WorkflowSession`, cast its session to a `org.apache.jackrabbit.api.JackrabbitSession`, which has a `getUserManager()` method:

```
JackrabbitSession js = (JackrabbitSession)workflowSession.getSession();
UserManager um = js.getUserManager();
```

Comment: Is it safe to use, 
`resourceResolverFactory.getThreadResourceResolver().adaptTo(UserManager.class) `

inside `WorkflowProcess`, to get `UserManager` ?

Comment: @Dileepa - Maybe it is safe, but it is not the way I would do it. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this below, because it is possible to get the available properties from UserProperties and API can tell us if it will be deprecated in future again:

```
    UserProperties up = request.adaptTo(UserProperties.class); 
    up.getProperty(UserProperties.EMAIL);
```